# Spring NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when accessing a bean from root context

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans

I have a root context file (applicationContext.xml) and a child context file (subContext.xml).

I get a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when I try to access a bean from applicationContext.xml  in subContext.xml

subContext.xml bean:

```
<bean id="myInfo" factory-bean="myInfoFactory"
    factory-method="getInstance" scope="request">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true" />
```

applicationContext.xml bean:

```
<bean id="myInfoFactory"
    class="org.wcw.factory.MyInfoFactory" />
```

Error I get is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myInfoFactory' is defined
```

web.xml

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

portlet.xml

```
<portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
        <value>/WEB-INF/subContext.xml</value>
    </init-param>
```

If I move the myInfoFactory bean declaration from applicationContext.xml to subContext.xml, it's not throwing that exception anymore. Not sure why it's invisible when declared in applicationContext.xml. I cannot permanently move the bean to subContext.xml because of my environment.
MyInfoFactory Class

```
public class MyInfoFactory {
private Logger log;
@Autowired
private PortletRequest request;

...
public MyInfo getInstance(PortletRequest request) {

  }
...

}
```

Comment: Please show how you initialize the contexts and what you mean by child context. Is it `import`ed?

Comment: Can you show the `MyInforFactory` class? At least a skeleton. This shouldn't be happening.

Comment: I've added the skeleton for MyInfoFactory. I haven't seen anything unsual going on in that class. Just some normal attributes and attributes!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is not about the configuration itself, but about where you are trying to recover that particular bean.

If you try to inject that request-scoped bean, defined in the child ApplicationContext (subContext.xml) from within a Bean defined in the Parent application context, the one given by the listener (applicationContext.xml) you won't be able to 'see' that particular been.

This relationship works in the other direction. The child can actually see every been defined in the parent container.

**One solution could be to move your request proxies to the parent, since they are proxies you can do that.** Though, a runtime will be thrown if no request available when you try to use that particular bean.